# I cant seem to push anymore, after updating podfile, .gitignore is not working and going back to previous commits isn't either

Tags: git

I have updated my pods and am trying to push some changes to my project. However, I have tried everything, git large file storage, putting my podfile into the .gitignore file and its still not working. I've even gone back to previous commits before I updated the pods, it still doesn't work.

The error I'm receiving is

```
! [remote rejected]

File Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds is 62.95 MB; this is larger than GitHub's recommended maximum file size of 50.00 MB
```

Why would it continue to say that if I have put the Pods directory into my .gitignore?

I have tried caching the directory using

```
git rm --cached Pods
```

Still no success.

I have tried creating a new branch, deleting the Podfile and adding, committing and pushing, still doesnt work.

I have tried

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Pods'
```

It still doesn't work.

I have tried putting this in my gitignore

```
Pods/*

git add .gitignore
git commit -m 'update .gitignore'
```

Then pushed, it still doesn't work. I understand I may have to remove Google AdMobs from my remote repository, but I'm unsure as to how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

#### TL;DR

You probably wanted:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch Pods'
```

Note the `-r` here.  But read more in case that wasn't quite what you meant.

#### Long

When you run `git push`, your Git connects to another Git—in this case, one on GitHub—and offers it *commits*.  That's not *files:* that's *commits*.  But commits do contain files.  So the real question here is: which *commit or commits* is your Git sending to their Git that contain the file:

```
Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds
```

You want to be rid of those commits, perhaps by replacing them with new-and-improved commits that contain all the other files, but not that one file.

You came pretty close with this:

> ```
> git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch Pods'
> ```

because `git filter-branch` means *take commits reachable from the starting points I list, and copy them to new-and-improved replacement commits that have these filters applied:* <insert list of your filters here>.  There are two ways this could have gone wrong, one of which is the most likely:

- The commit(s) in question aren't reachable from your current commit.  For a long discussion on branch names and reachability, read through the tutorial at [Think Like (a) Git](http://think-like-a-git.net/).  This web site is a good idea once you've used Git for a while.

  The reason this one is *not* likely where things went wrong is that the default for `git push` is to send commits that are on your current branch (except that you don't need to send any that the Git on GitHub not already has).  This is also the default for `git filter-branch`: all commits on the *current* branch.  Since you didn't name any starting point, both commands operated on the *current* branch.

  (You didn't show your actual `git push` command, nor your Git version, so I had to make a reasonable guess here.  Otherwise I could be 100% certain that this *isn't* the problem.)
- The filter you listed is inadequate for accomplishing the improvements.

  The filter you gave was an index filter consisting of the request to remove a *file* named `Pods`, without complaining if there is no such file.  The file you need to remove isn't named `Pods` at all, it's named `Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds`.

  You can add the `-r` flag, which tells Git to remove *any* file whose path name *begins with* `Pods/`.  That would remove not only `Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework/GoogleMobileAds` but also `Pods/This/Is/A/Silly/Made/Up/File/Name` and so on.

  Or, you can spell out the one particular file and leave off the `-r` flag.
- Or, of course, both situations might apply, but I would bet on the middle one only—you want an improved `--index-filter`.

Whether the improvement is to use `-r`, or to spell out the full file name, or something in between—perhaps:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK/Frameworks/frameworks/GoogleMobileAds.framework'
```

or:

```
git filter-branch --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch Pods/Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK'
```

for instance—is a question that only you can answer: which files do you want in your commits, and which ones don't you want?  (Note that the commits don't contain any directories, in a sense: they only contain *files* as named by their full names.  Git will *automatically create* any containing directories if and when that's necessary.)

Comment: Thanks for your in depth response.

Ok, so I tried all of those, except the last one and they didn't work. I went to try the last one and I thought I would also try the following

git filter-branch -f --index-filter 'git rm -r --cached --ignore-unmatch DerivedData'

As it said that DerivedData was taking up 128MB and limit was 100MB.

But now I am getting this error...

fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/User/project.git' : SSL: no alternative certificate subject name matches target host name 'github.com'

Comment: The SSL error suggests that either you're contacting a machine that *isn't* GitHub (but is lying and claiming to be GitHub and then failing to match the real certifications), or more likely, some other SSL error. It's not clear how you're contacting GitHub (https or ssh) nor what version of support software you're using. https://www.google.com/search?q=no+alternative+certificate+subject+name+matches+target+host+name turns up quite a lot of background information.

Comment: with regard to your final question, I am only looking to ignore the files that are stopping me from pushing, so the Google-Mob-Ad-SDK and the Derived Data (which is over 100MB). I don't understand why it has all of a sudden started causing a problem.

Comment: You might want to check the sizes of the larger objects in your repository: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+find+large+file